# S-grid for eigenvalues map on tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I'm currently working with eigenvalues analysis and to that I don't use the normal grid, but the s-grid (grid of constant damping factors and natural frequencies). I use the function `matlab2tikz` to export my graphs but I'm having a problem with the way the function generates this kind of grid. So, I'm trying to make my own s-grid with TikZ.

[image: matlab s-grid]

After some research, I didn't find anything that was already made for `TikZ` (there was some posts about the Z-grid...). So far, I made some progress... Although I'm having some problems as well (code provided below).

[image: my s-grid]

**First:** to draw my circumference, I split my function in two to respect it as a function. Although, I don't understand why my function doesn't is evaluate up to y = 0. It's bother me most because the values of the radius aren't aligned.

**Second:** as you can see, my nodes for `$\xi$` aren't evaluated before print. I have tried many syntaxes without success. Apparently, there's a problem in evaluate it inside the axis environment. Also related to this node, because the value can be greater than the plot limit, the midway point can be outside the plot, not displaying the text. Is it possible to have a midway point considering the plot limit?

**Third (and last):** because this grid will be applied to different figures, is there a method to express it as a function of `$xi$` and `$\omega$` (basically as a function of the values of `pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and the domain)?

Sorry for the long post and thank you all!

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=0,
        ymin=-10,
        ymax=10,
        samples=500]


        \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs: 0,0);
        \coordinate (lim1) at (axis cs:{-(tan(asin(0.05)))*10},10);
        \coordinate (lim2) at (axis cs:{-(tan(asin(0.05)))*10},-10);
        \coordinate (ymax) at (axis cs:0,10);
        \coordinate (ymin) at (axis cs:0,-10);


        \draw[dashed,red] (origin) -- (lim1) node[font=\tiny,anchor=north,midway,sloped,inner sep=0pt] {$\xi=5\%$};
        \draw[dashed,red] (origin) -- (lim2) node[font=\tiny,anchor=south,midway,sloped,inner sep=0pt] {$\xi=5\%$};
        \draw[draw=red,fill=red,opacity=0.2] (origin) -- (lim1) -- (ymax) -- cycle;
        \draw[draw=red,fill=red,opacity=0.2] (origin) -- (lim2) -- (ymin) -- cycle;

        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{4,10,25}{
            \coordinate (p1) at (axis cs:{-#1},10);
            \coordinate (p2) at (axis cs:{-#1},-10);
            \draw[dashed] (origin) -- (p1) node[font=\tiny,anchor=north,midway,sloped,inner sep=0pt] {$\xi=${100*cos(atan(-X/Y))}\%};
            \draw[dashed] (origin) -- (p2) node[font=\tiny,anchor=south,midway,sloped,inner sep=0pt] {$\xi=${100*cos(atan(-X/Y))}\%};
        }       

        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {2,4,6,8,10}{
            \addplot[domain=0:10, dashed] (-x,{sqrt(#1^2-x^2)}) node [at end,anchor=south,font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt,fill=white,]{#1};
            \addplot[domain=0:10, dashed] (-x,-{sqrt(#1^2-x^2)});
        }


    \addplot [color=red, draw=none, mark size=2pt, mark=diamond*, mark options={solid,fill=red}]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        -0.062  5.971\\
        -0.062  -5.971\\
        -0.100  0.000\\
        -0.100  0.000\\
        -0.142  0.000\\
        -0.185  0.000\\
        -2.539  0.000\\
        -3.139  0.000\\
        -4.763  0.000\\
        -8  0.000\\
    };


    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately I am only able to understand point 1. You can avoid the problems by choosing a different parametrization. Instead of `x` and `sqrt(#1^2-x^2)` you can parametrize the plot as `#1*cos(<angle>)` and `#1*sin(<angle>)`, i.e. `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {2,4,6,8,10}{
            \addplot[domain=90:270,samples=61, dashed] ({#1*cos(x)},{#1*sin(x)})
   node [pos=0.5,anchor=south,font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt,fill=white,]{#1};
        }` (where the angle was denoted `x`). Could you perhaps explain the other points more?

Comment: Specifically, I do not understand "as you can see, my nodes for `$\xi$` aren't evaluated before print".  There are many nodes with `\xi`, but I fail to see any where any contents get evaluated. The last point I also do not understand. There are polar axes available, are you looking for those?